# What is "RailsFCGIHandler" doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

What is `"RailsFCGIHandler"` doing? It has a `process!` method, seems starts a Rails Application, if so, what's the difference between `rails server` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RailsFCGIHandler` is the glue between a webserver speaking the fastcgi protocol and a rails application.

Once upon a time, this was a popular way of hosting rails application with apache or lighttpd.

Comment: So can I say if I do not use Apache/lightpd as Reverse Proxy, only use a Rails server(ex: `Phusion Passenger`), then I can use `rails server` to start it, while if I use Apache/lightpd as Reverse Proxy, and `Phusion Passenger` as Application server, then `RailsFCGIHandler` is the connection between Apache and `Phusion Passenger` and can be used to start the Application server(that is, `Phusion Passenger`), I'm I right?

Comment: No - it's only used if you use mod_fcgi / mod_fastcgi

Comment: Rails is not started by `RailsFCGIHandler`